# How return works in JS behind the scenes

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and wanted to deeply understand how return in JS works. For example, here are some code examples: `let num = function(){return 5}` and `function number(){return 5}  console.log(number())`. The question is for example, in the second example Will number() which was passed to console.log() be replaced with the value that number() returns, that is, will console.log(number()) turn into console.log(5) behind the scenes. When we return something from a function then will that function be replaced with the value it returns. Is it what happens behind the scenes when we return a value from a function?

Comment: The function will be evaluated and its return value will be passed to the `console.log` function as the first argument

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb, So you mean in  console.log(number()) number() will be taken out and be replaced with 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both assign a name to a function, but one of them perform at run time, the other at compile time (or at begin of running), that's why if you call number it's known even if it defined below the call, but for the other, it should first get assigned.

the `return` work the same in both, returning value 5. when you used () for calling the function.

for more information on JS structure i suggest `You don't Know JS` book. i'm not sure if it's allowed to suggest a book here, but it's free to read: 
[You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/1st-ed)

### Update

**If by any change i got you wrong, and you are looking for a way to pass the actual function:**

When you are calling `num()` or `number()` inside the `console.log()` like this:

```
console.log(num())
```

It will process the 'num()' first, and then return the value which is '5', then that value, is passed to `console.log(value)` in here `console.log(5)`.

If you are looking for a way to pass the actual function/expression to the sub function, like what `C#` `LINQ` or `Java` `Stream` does, you need the secondary function to call the function it self. for example:

in here i wrote a function which filter out item of array, when user condition is true...
Here condition is a function which passed to this function by user... and get called by secondary function...

```
function filter(list, condition) {
  let  result=[];
  for(let i = 0; i < list.length ; i++) {
    if(condition(list[i])) {
      result.push(list[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

let condition = function(item) {
  return item.isOk;
}
```

and you call it like this:

```
filter(myArray, condition)
```

Note: i used `condition` instead of 'condition()', now we passed the actual function instead of the value returned by that function

Comment: hi Hassan, still I cannot get. Can I imagine it like this, in console.log(number()) number() will be taken out and be replaced with 5? If not, can you kindly say where I am wrong. Thank you

Comment: @Dickens when you invoke a function, i.e `number()` it executes the code you have inside your function and return the value and then that value is passed as argument to console.log, in the end it will be `console.log(5)`

Comment: @CodeManiac, thank you for your kind comments, if we finally have console.log(5) then where is number() passed into console.log(), I mean we initially had console.log(number()) then finally have console.log(5). number() is kind of replaced with the number it returns? Sorry I am saying the same thing but this is what I think happens logically. Right?

Comment: @CodeManiac, please I really need your help:(

Comment: I don't get what you are looking for, but in here: `let num = function(){return 5}` or the other, the function is defined, then once you call `num()` or `number()` it try to get the returned value, which is 5, and the console.log(...) process that value, not the number() function...
 BUT, if you need to pass the function it self, you should pass `num` or `number`, instead of `num()` or `number()`, then within the other function you can process the value of that function... I add it as an update to my answer

Comment: @Dickens you please re-read my comment, if executes `nubmer()` and the return value of that function is then printed by console.log on screen.

Comment: yes the value of that function is returned on console.... do right click, then click on inspect element, go to console tab, and write: `let num = function() {return 5}`, press enter, you get `undefined` dont care about it, then write `console.log(num())`, you get another `undefined`, and the printed value, which is `5`

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you are assigning anonymous function yo a variable `num`. That is called function expression. But function has not been executed, so the `num` will remain a function/object. To get the value from the function you should execute that with the parentheses `num()`. Or if you want immediately return value and assign that to a variable you should do like this:

`let num = (function () { 
    return 5
  })()`

In your second example you first declare function and then in your `console.log` before showing on console you executes that `number` function and returns `5` and only after that your `console.log` will be executed and `5` will be passed as an argument.